# How do I keep an egg from cracking while being boiled?

Tags: eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

I know it's a stupid question and I really am quite the amateur when it comes to cooking, but this problem occurred rather very frequently to me.

The egg moves in the boiling water and often it hits the wall of the pot and cracks, making a mess. No matter how little water I use, I can't avoid it. Any way out?

Comment: I'm not trying to hard boil in particular. Thanks though. :)

Comment: OP is from Australia; hard boil is just an expression for boiling, it doesn't actually have to mean boiling an egg until hard. Either way, they problem and solutions are the same

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions here:

- Very slowly increase the temperature of the water. This way, the
  water currents will be much tamer, and the egg is much less likely to
  move around.
- You could also try either cooking the egg in a heat-resistant spoon to minimize its movement, or fill the pot with many eggs, so they have less room to move around and gently bump each other rather than the walls of the pot.

Comment: Please move answer to linked question as this is a duplicate

Comment: The question hasn't been marked as a duplicate yet (still awaiting peer review). Also, @soham-gosh said that the linked question wasn't the same in a comment upon the original post.

Comment: Aaronut has the best answer over on the other version of this question. You can purchase egg piercers cheaply, or you can just pick up a sharp or two at the local drug store to use in piercing the egg to allow vapor to escape.